# Tensorflow -- Iterating over training and validation sequencially

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have been going throught the Dataset API of tensorflow to feed different dataset with ease to an RNN model.

I got everything working following the not so many blogs together with the docs in the tensorflow website. My working example did the following:

**--- Train on X epochs in a training dataset -> validate after all the training has concluded in a validation dataset.**

However, I'm unable to develop the following example:

**--- Train on X epochs in a training dataset -> validate in each epoch the training model with a validation dataset (a bit like what Keras does)**

The problematic issue comes because of the following piece of code:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y)).batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True).repeat()

val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y)).batch(BATCH_SIZE_VAL, drop_remainder=True).repeat()

itr = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, train_dataset.output_shapes)
train_init_op = itr.make_initializer(train_dataset)
validation_init_op = itr.make_initializer(val_dataset)
```

*When I create the iterator from_structure, I need to specify an output_shape. Obviously, the output shape of the train dataset and the validation dataset is not the same as they have a different batch_size. However, the validation_init_op is throwing the following error, which it seems counterintuitive because validation sets have always different batch_size:*

```
TypeError: Expected output shapes compatible with (TensorShape([Dimension(256), Dimension(11), Dimension(74)]), TensorShape([Dimension(256), Dimension(3)])) but got dataset with output shapes (TensorShape([Dimension(28), Dimension(11), Dimension(74)]), TensorShape([Dimension(28), Dimension(3)])).
```

I want to do this second approach to evaluate my model and see the common train and validation plots developed at the same time, to see how can I improve it (stopping the learning early and etc). However, with the first simple approach I don't get all this.

**So, the question is: ¿Am I doing something wrong? ¿Does my second approach has to be tackled differently?** I can think of creating two iterators, but I don't know if that is the right approach. Also, this answer by @MatthewScarpino points out to a **feedable iterator** because switching between reinitializable ones makes them to start all over again; however, the above error is not related with that part of the code -- **¿Maybe the reinitializable iterator is not intended to set a different batch size for the validation set and to only iterate it once after training whatever the size it is and without setting it in the `.batch()` method?**

Any help is very much appreciated.

Full code for reference:

```
N_TIMESTEPS_X = xt.shape[0] ## The stack number
BATCH_SIZE = 256
#N_OBSERVATIONS = xt.shape[1]
N_FEATURES = xt.shape[2]
N_OUTPUTS = yt.shape[1]
N_NEURONS_LSTM = 128 ## Number of units in the LSTMCell 
N_EPOCHS = 350
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001

### Define the placeholders anda gather the data.
xt = xt.transpose([1,0,2])
xval = xval.transpose([1,0,2])

train_data = (xt, yt)
validation_data = (xval, yval)

N_BATCHES = train_data[0].shape[0] // BATCH_SIZE
print('The number of batches is: {}'.format(N_BATCHES))
BATCH_SIZE_VAL = validation_data[0].shape[0] // N_BATCHES
print('The validation batch size is: {}'.format(BATCH_SIZE_VAL))

## We define the placeholders as a trick so that we do not break into memory problems, associated with feeding the data directly.
'''As an alternative, you can define the Dataset in terms of tf.placeholder() tensors, and feed the NumPy arrays when you initialize an Iterator over the dataset.'''
batch_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, N_TIMESTEPS_X, N_FEATURES], name='XPlaceholder')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, N_OUTPUTS], name='YPlaceholder')

# Creating the two different dataset objects.
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y)).batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True).repeat()
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y)).batch(BATCH_SIZE_VAL, drop_remainder=True).repeat()

# Creating the Iterator type that permits to switch between datasets.
itr = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, train_dataset.output_shapes)
train_init_op = itr.make_initializer(train_dataset)
validation_init_op = itr.make_initializer(val_dataset)

next_features, next_labels = itr.get_next()
```

Comment: can you explain more about why the feedable iterator doesnt work because it looks like the solution? Because right now its difficult to say what the problem is without seeing more of your code, specifically the training and validation codes which use these datasets in the overall process.

Comment: Hi @kvish, thanks for the time. The feedable iterator is something that I haven’t tried, so it may be the solution to the problem; I just was asking if there was someone that has used it to do my same approach. The thing is that the above error is regarding the reinitializable iterator init op. I will be developing the feedable iterator this afternoon. Let’s see if I have success.

Comment: I think in general using either iterator needs same shape guarantees. General use case is same validation shape like training shape. Is there any particular reason why you might want to have a different shape for validation than train?

Comment: I think maybe using 2 iterators can be best in that case, as it gives you the flexibility to define the data in the shape that fits your memory requirements

Comment: @kvish for my understanding, the shape "is" the same. What I mean is that, obviously the validation dataset must have less observations than the train dataset. The other shapes are just okey, that is why I don't get which is the issue. Also, creating the two iterators can be a good idea. I'm just finishing the feedable one. Let me check the two iterator option and I will edit the question.

Comment: @kvish I think that the option of two iterators cannot work or the implementation is a bit rare. I need to create two `.get_next()` methods, which results in: how do I feed the two .get_next() values to the graph? For example, I would need to create two graphs? And the following code should be duplicated: `inputs = tf.unstack(next_features, axis=1)` -- Any idea? I will follow with the feedable one.

Comment: I think I'm getting the point: ¿does the batch size need to be the same in both datasets? In that case, I should manage the number of batches differently, because the number of batches will be different between the two datasets. Thoughts @kvish?

Comment: If you define 2 iterators, you can define 2 initializable iterators, run the iterator initializer for both before using them. It would still work pretty well. The cases where the complexity would arise is if you checkpointed somewhere in the middle of training and had to resume from there, in which case you would need to save the iterator state to resume from where you left off. Otherwise you can afford to go through the iterators again and again after initializing them before using right?

Comment: Regarding the batch size requirement, it would be very comfortable for you to have the same for both training and validation. This is because you're just evaluating the loss and accuracy and that is not going to be any different because of batchsize. This allows you to use both re-initializable iterators or feedable iterators without having to worry about how you handle the graph

Comment: Regarding the shape, the shape in the dataset includes the first dimension which is the batch-size. So the shape as such would be different in this case as the number of elements in the batch are differing. As you said, the other dimensions have the same shape.

Comment: Thanks @kvish. I have just answered my question so as to have a clean solution that works on my end. Again, thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the best way to do this, I came across with this final implementation that works well on my end. Surely not be the best. So as to maintain the state, I used a **feedable iterator**.

**AIM:** This code is intented to be used when you want to train and validate at the same time, preserving the state of each iterator (i.e. validate with the newest model parameters). Together with that, the code saves the model and other stuff, like some information about the hyperparameters and summaries to visualize the training and validation in Tensorboard.

**Also, don't get confused:** you don't need to have a different batch size for the training set and for the validation set. This is a misconception that I have. The batch sizes must be the same AND you have to deal with the different number of batches, just passing when no more batches are left. This is a requirement so that you can create the iterator, regarding having both datasets the same data type and shape.

Hope it helps others. Just ignore the code that does not relate to your objectives. **Many thanks for @kvish for all the help and time.**

**Code:**

```
def RNNmodelTF(xt, yt, xval, yval, xtest, ytest):

N_TIMESTEPS_X = xt.shape[0] ## The stack number
BATCH_SIZE = 256
#N_OBSERVATIONS = xt.shape[1]
N_FEATURES = xt.shape[2]
N_OUTPUTS = yt.shape[1]
N_NEURONS_LSTM = 128 ## Number of units in the LSTMCell 
N_EPOCHS = 350
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001

### Define the placeholders anda gather the data.
xt = xt.transpose([1,0,2])
xval = xval.transpose([1,0,2])

train_data = (xt, yt)
validation_data = (xval, yval)

N_BATCHES = train_data[0].shape[0] // BATCH_SIZE

## We define the placeholders as a trick so that we do not break into memory problems, associated with feeding the data directly.
'''As an alternative, you can define the Dataset in terms of tf.placeholder() tensors, and feed the NumPy arrays when you initialize an Iterator over the dataset.'''
batch_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, N_TIMESTEPS_X, N_FEATURES], name='XPlaceholder')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, N_OUTPUTS], name='YPlaceholder')

# Creating the two different dataset objects.
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y)).batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True).repeat()
val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x,y)).batch(BATCH_SIZE, drop_remainder=True).repeat()

#################### Creating the Iterator type that permits to switch between datasets.

handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape = [])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(handle, train_dataset.output_types, train_dataset.output_shapes)
next_features, next_labels = iterator.get_next()

train_val_iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, train_dataset.output_shapes)
train_iterator = train_val_iterator.make_initializer(train_dataset)
val_iterator = train_val_iterator.make_initializer(val_dataset)

###########################

### Create the graph 
cellType = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units=N_NEURONS_LSTM, name='LSTMCell')
inputs = tf.unstack(next_features, axis=1)
'''inputs: A length T list of inputs, each a Tensor of shape [batch_size, input_size]'''
RNNOutputs, _ = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell=cellType, inputs=inputs, dtype=tf.float32)
out_weights = tf.get_variable("out_weights", shape=[N_NEURONS_LSTM, N_OUTPUTS], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
out_bias = tf.get_variable("out_bias", shape=[N_OUTPUTS], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
predictionsLayer = tf.matmul(RNNOutputs[-1], out_weights) + out_bias

### Define the cost function, that will be optimized by the optimizer. 
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(logits=predictionsLayer, labels=next_labels, name='Softmax_plus_Cross_Entropy'))
optimizer_type = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, name='AdamOptimizer')
optimizer = optimizer_type.minimize(cost)

### Model evaluation 
correctPrediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictionsLayer,1), tf.argmax(next_labels,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correctPrediction,tf.float32))

confusionMatrix1 = tf.confusion_matrix(tf.argmax(next_labels,1), tf.argmax(predictionsLayer,1), num_classes=3, name='ConfMatrix')

## Saving variables so that we can restore them afterwards.
saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_dir = '/media/SecondDiskHDD/8classModels/DLmodels/tfModels/{}_{}'.format(cellType.__class__.__name__, datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
#save_dir = '/home/Desktop/tfModels/{}_{}'.format(cellType.__class__.__name__, datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"))
os.mkdir(save_dir)
varDict = {'nTimeSteps': N_TIMESTEPS_X, 'BatchSize': BATCH_SIZE, 'nFeatures': N_FEATURES,
           'nNeuronsLSTM': N_NEURONS_LSTM, 'nEpochs': N_EPOCHS,
           'learningRate': LEARNING_RATE, 'optimizerType': optimizer_type.__class__.__name__}
varDicSavingTxt = save_dir + '/varDict.txt'
modelFilesDir = save_dir + '/modelFiles'
os.mkdir(modelFilesDir)

logDir = save_dir + '/TBoardLogs'
os.mkdir(logDir)

acc_summary = tf.summary.scalar('Accuracy', accuracy)
loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('Cost_CrossEntropy', cost)
summary_merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

with open(varDicSavingTxt, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(repr(varDict))

with tf.Session() as sess:

    tf.set_random_seed(2)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logDir + '/train', sess.graph)
    validation_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logDir + '/validation')

    # initialise iterator with data
    train_val_string = sess.run(train_val_iterator.string_handle())

    cm1Total = None
    cm2Total = None

    print('¡Training starts!')
    for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):

        batchAccList = []
        batchAccListVal = []
        tot_loss_train = 0
        tot_loss_validation = 0

        for batch in range(N_BATCHES):

            sess.run(train_iterator, feed_dict = {x : train_data[0], y: train_data[1], batch_size: BATCH_SIZE})
            optimizer_output, loss_value, summary, accBatch, cm1 = sess.run([optimizer, cost, summary_merged, accuracy, confusionMatrix1], feed_dict = {handle: train_val_string})

            npArrayPred = predictionsLayer.eval(feed_dict= {handle: train_val_string})
            predLabEnc = np.apply_along_axis(thresholdSet, 1, npArrayPred, value=0.5)

            npArrayLab = next_labels.eval(feed_dict= {handle: train_val_string})
            labLabEnc = np.argmax(npArrayLab, 1)

            cm2 = confusion_matrix(labLabEnc, predLabEnc)
            tot_loss_train += loss_value
            batchAccList.append(accBatch)

            try:
                sess.run(val_iterator, feed_dict = {x: validation_data[0], y: validation_data[1], batch_size: BATCH_SIZE})
                valLoss, valAcc, summary_val = sess.run([cost, accuracy, summary_merged], feed_dict = {handle: train_val_string})
                tot_loss_validation += valLoss
                batchAccListVal.append(valAcc)

            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                pass

            if cm1Total is None and cm2Total is None:

                cm1Total = cm1
                cm2Total = cm2
            else:

                cm1Total += cm1
                cm2Total += cm2

            if batch % 10 == 0:

                train_writer.add_summary(summary, batch)
                validation_writer.add_summary(summary_val, batch)

        epochAcc = tf.reduce_mean(batchAccList)
        sess.run(train_iterator, feed_dict = {x : train_data[0], y: train_data[1], batch_size: BATCH_SIZE})
        epochAcc_num = sess.run(epochAcc, feed_dict = {handle: train_val_string})

        epochAccVal = tf.reduce_mean(batchAccListVal)
        sess.run(val_iterator, feed_dict = {x: validation_data[0], y: validation_data[1], batch_size: BATCH_SIZE})
        epochAcc_num_Val = sess.run(epochAccVal, feed_dict = {handle: train_val_string})

        if epoch%10 == 0:

            print("Epoch: {}, Loss: {:.4f}, Accuracy: {:.3f}".format(epoch, tot_loss_train / N_BATCHES, epochAcc_num))
            print('Validation Loss: {:.4f}, Validation Accuracy: {:.3f}'.format(tot_loss_validation / N_BATCHES, epochAcc_num_Val))

    cmLogFile1 = save_dir + '/cm1File.txt'
    with open(cmLogFile1, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(repr(cm1Total))

    cmLogFile2 = save_dir + '/cm2File.txt'
    with open(cmLogFile2, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(repr(cm2Total))

    saver.save(sess, modelFilesDir + '/model.ckpt')
```